# Why do I have more mana than allowed?

Tags: child-of-light

I just resumed the game from where I left off the last time and I noticed that I have 31 out of 29 mana points. How could this happen?

[image]

Comment: Did you swap out an emerald occuli placed in the accessories position? Occuli placed in that position increases the mana cap.

Comment: It was a long time ago now, and the game was resumed from turned off computer, so there's no way I remember that.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume you have an item equipped that buffs your MP, I'd check your equipment to see if any have an effect on MP

Comment: haha that was a few windows reinstallations ago, I don't think I can do that now :p

Comment: Oh dang I didn't realize this question was from so long ago xD Nevermind, hoped I helped haha